# Increment value not incremnting on return

Tags: php

this is what i am doing. I am incrementing php var through a function like:

```
<?php $j=1; ?>

jQuery('.mysubmitbuttin').click(function(){

increment();

});

function increment()
{
    var inc = '<?php echo $j=$j+1; ?>';
    alert(inc);
    return inc;
}
```

the alert inc showing 2 everytime. php var $j is not incrementing the value. why is it so?

Comment: You can not mix jQuery code and PHP code like this.

Comment: how then i should inc my $j value?

Comment: Jack, that is not a php function, that is a JS function. Anyway, then I've read the post you suggest, and realised, that was a good to close. Sorry, I can not cancel my reopen request.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Yeah, it's a JavaScript function trying to call a piece of PHP code; same rule applies :)

Answer (score 0):

php-code is only executed once on the SERVER ! before you get the DOM-Element